# matlab rearrange (permute) string array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a string array:

```
size(entries)

 ans =

            1       19413
```

I would like to rearrange the array to 4853 rows and 4 columns:

```
output=permute(entries,[4853 4]);
```

but get following error:

> Error using permute ORDER contains an invalid permutation index.

What is the (probably obvious thing) I am doing wrong? thanks

Comment: Use `reshape` instead.

Comment: *Obvious* thing would be you are not reading the docs.

Comment: I removed the `permute` tag.  It refers to a package in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You currently have 19413 elements, yet you wish to reshape this into a `4853 x 4` matrix that consists of `4853 * 4 = 19412` elements.  No function in the world will help you do this because the original and target amount of elements don't match - they're off by one element.  If you remove one of the elements...say... the last one, then we're getting somewhere.

Supposing you made a mistake and included that extra element by accident, you don't use `permute` here, but you use [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html).  The second argument to `reshape` is the amount of elements to spread out for each target dimension, and that's what you're looking for.  First remove the extraneous element that appears at the end of the array, then `reshape` the matrix:

```
output = reshape(entries(1:end-1),[4853 4]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm 3 years late, but here's to anyone still looking for an answer.

In your case as mentioned above, yes you should use `reshape()` while minding that you preserve the total number of elements.

You use `permute()` when you want to reorder the dimensionality of an **n-dimensional (ND) matrix**.

The `ORDER` parameter specifies the order of the columns.

For example, if matrix A is LxMxN, the following line would make it MxLxN.

```
A = permute(A,[2 1 3]);
```

Hope this clears things.